# Is asynchronous threading an option if my GUI relies on data retrieved from a database?

Tags: java, multithreading, google-cloud-firestore

I'm very new to Java's multithreading. I recently found out that a new thread is automatically created when trying to access data from Firestore.

In my mobile application, after the login screen, the GUI relies on data retrieved from Firestore. Is there any way I can benefit from asynchronous threading in this case or am I forced to wait for data retrieval? What's good practice in this case?

Also, I'd highly appreciate it if anyone can provide me with a good source to start getting acquainted with multithreading.

Comment: Firebase SDKs already perform network and disk I/O off the main thread, so you should never be waiting for that in your main/UI thread. We may be able to help better if you show an example of the problem you're trying to solve, as right now this reads like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

You should always assume data pulled from any online service has an inherent delay and should be handled through async means. as for threading, this is not needed with Firebase as it runs on the main thread.

It is suggested to use template loading models that have gray or loading placeholders until the data is synced to the client, you may see this in other apps as a spinner or a grey box until it loads or times out, which you should also consider if the user is offline.

Firebase manages their own app instance including a local cache for Firestore to help reduce reads and loading time, utilizing a combination of these features with async/await methods will smooth out any issues you may have with rendering data to render with a GUI.